# What is meant by exception handling?

Tags: exception

Hi there I have a question, What is meant by Exception Handling? 
Also when should exception handling should & shouldn't be employed.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html

Comment: This is a very broad question (that is better suited for the programmers stackexchange?)  Exception handling is generally whatever a language designer understands exception handling to be and implements in a language.

Comment: put quite simply, adding workarounds for conditions to your program that can arise, however aren't within the normal intended program flow, for example, accounting for blank user input, database not being able to be connected to, etc.  As to when it should/shouldn't be employed....well I can't think of any (non trivial) program that shouldn't have some level of exception handling.  You will always need to account for user and system faults.

Answer (score 1):

First link after typing **Exception handling** on google gave me [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling):-

> Exception handling is the process of responding to the occurrence,
>   during computation, of exceptions – anomalous or exceptional events
>   requiring special processing – often changing the normal flow of
>   program execution. It is provided by specialized programming language
>   constructs or computer hardware mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

What "exception handling" means is language-dependent, but usually there is some concept of handling rare situations (such as environmental resource errors, or numeric problems) outside of the normal program control, including decisions about how and where to continue the program, so that this logic doesn't have to be inconveniently woven into the code.

Exception handling systems usually represent exception situations in some way, which might consist of numeric codes, or in an object-oriented way in which exceptions are classes that have properties and are related by inheritance, that inheritance being used as a key pattern matching mechanism in the search for a suitable handler.

How exception handling is implemented can widely differ. Some exception handling systems, notably those implemented in hardware, meticulously preserve all machine state during the exception processing and can re-start the program precisely from the instruction which raised the exception. This type of exception handling allows virtual memory to work quite transparently.

Other exception handling systems discard program state by "unwinding the stack" during the search for a handler. The underlying assumption is that the situation is not recoverable in a detailed manner; and all that is possible is a complete or partial exit with careful cleanup of resources and roll-back of any transaction-like contexts.

Some kinds of exception systems, like PL/I or Common Lisp, provide an "in between" solution: restartable exceptions, without the meticulously detailed handling of machine state as in CPU exceptions handled by the operating system.  The key difference is that the exception handler isn't the point where the program continues, and that an exception handler is a newly activated procedure that is invoked before any unwinding takes place. A higher level function can provide an exception handler as a kind of callback to lower level code, which is invoked without having to take place and destroy the context which spans from the higher level code to the lower level code.  The handler can then decide how to continue the lower level code where the situation occurred.

When exception handling should and should not be used depends on what kind of exception handling it is (and what kinds of performance impact it has) and how it is being applied, with regard to the requirements for the piece of software in consideration. Even when all of these are known, there is room for opinion. Exception handling systems can be used for situations which are not unexpected at all, provided the overhead is acceptable.

CPU exception handling, for instance, can be used to emulate missing machine instructions (or CPU features, like misaligned memory accesses). This approach performs poorly compared to true hardware implementation of the instructions, but it allows programs to run which otherwise cannot.  If the programs for which this is intended to be used have adequate performance, then it is fine. Programming language exception handling can be potentially used in many situations where otherwise some kind of return value test would be applied. When processing a file sequentially until the end, the end-of-file can be detected via an exception. The code simply assumes that a unit of data can be read from the file without checking any error condition; when data cannot be read, the exception is thrown and caught somewhere, thereby terminating the loop. If this approach performs well, the code organization it brings about may be worthwhile, even though the end of a file is not an unexpected error situation.